# What guitar chord is made up of the open notes A D G B?

Tags: guitar, chords

Guitar chord is cited as a chord in Kenny Wayne Sheppard's Born With a Broken Heart.

Comment: Cited where? It sounds like an A minor blues played tuned down a half step. If anything the B is actually a C.

Answer (score 7):

Because those notes don’t form a basic triad or seventh chord (instrument doesn’t matter), the interpretation depends on the surrounding context.

Answer (score 5):

With A being the lowest note and not repeated higher, I'd call it a G/A (i. e. G with added bass A).

Answer (score 2):

D G and B form the very simple G major triad, if it's in that rising order, it'll be 2nd inversion.

Adding an A note in there  will introduce a 2nd (rather than a 9th) to the title, and as that A doesn't knock out the B it won't be a sus (or ret). So best title is Gadd2/A.

Comment: Since the lowest note (A) is not repeated higher I would rather say as @Divizna suggested: It is G/A (i. e. G with added bass A).

Answer (score 1):

On a six string guitar, with the top and bottom E strings muted, strumming those four notes downward would chime the 5th, 4th, 3rd, and 2nd strings.

This, in that context, is an Asus9 guitar chord.

It is also known as, and Divisna indicated as much, a G/A chord.

I hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

G9, Amin11, A9sus4
In reality the chosen chord is context based

Answer (score -1):

so, this chord is the 4 inside open strings? Whatever this "chord" would be called, if a chord at all, would have to do with the musical context in which it occurs.

The song you mention is a 12 bar blues in A flat. Where you got this chord from, I don't know. Some weird tab or other. It makes no sense in the context of this song. It looks like a mistake.